# A NaturalSpec method with ' in name not found on Mono

Tags: f#, mono, monodevelop

I've managed to compile NaturalSpec on mono and am trying an F# library project in MonoDevelop using it.  The README test fails:

```
module ListSpec
open NaturalSpec

[<Scenario>]
let When_removing_an_3_from_a_small_list_it_should_not_contain_3() =
  Given [1;2;3;4;5]
    |> When removing 3
    |> It shouldn't contain 3
    |> Verify
```

-- with the error that `NaturalSpec.Syntax.shouldn't method` is not found.  Replacing that by a `should` test rectifies that.  Is there a problem for mono to use a method with an apostrophe in it?  Compilation works fine, so that method is seen, but cannot be found at runtime?

Comment: I just tested and methods with `'` in the name work fine for me in both `fsi` and `fsc` - on Mono v 2.10.2 and fsi v2.0.0.0 - so the problem is something else

Comment: What Mono version are you using? Might be that you found a regression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up recompiling NaturalSpec with F# 3.0 and .NET framework 4.5 from Mono 3.0.0, and then doing exactly the same with my own project.  Apparently, when you open NaturalSpec.fsproj, you get .NET 3.5 as a default.  Also, even with Mono 3.0.0, the default F# was 2.0.  I've installed F# from open source code drop separately and specified fsc and fsi from it as in F# preferences in MonoDevelop.  Now I made that NaturalSpec a reference, and unit tests are showing up properly in MonoDevelop -- a great way to do TDD in Mono.